# jquery mobile changepage switching to wrong page first

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a phonegap app using jquery mobile.

It's a really big app so I'm not able to post all my javascript code. but I have a google map in my app and it has overlay buttons, if attached a function that gets executed when I push the button. Normally it should just link to a page with the id #list.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#list", {
    transition: "slide"
});
```

The app has a navigation like this

home->map->list

Now when I click the button on the map that runs above code, it should just go the list page, but it first goes to the home page, then to the list page, this looks bad, but also when I press the back button it returns to the home page, not to the map page.

anyone seen this problem before?

some info:

android 2.3

htc desire HD

jquery 1.8

jquery mobile 1.2

phonegap 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I initiated phonegap twice!